# JavaScript called in C# Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to call a JS function in my RazorModel file that alerts the user that he has logged in successfully.

I've tried using TempDatas, ViewDatas, ModelStates and even static variables but to no vail.

After some searches I saw that you can you ScriptManager to call JS code, but I can not reference to System.Web.UI as I am running ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Here is my method that is getting POST Called. I want to show the alert() before the redirect to homepage.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {                       
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

UPDATE:
Solved my problem using localStorage based javaScript to save a variable so that I can track usage.

In my _LoginPartial

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var loginPrompt = localStorage.getItem("loginPrompt")
            if (loginPrompt != 1) {
                alert("Bine te-am gasit zeule! Hai si ia niste Doge.")
                localStorage.setItem("loginPrompt", 1)
            };
        });
    </script>
}
else
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            localStorage.setItem("loginPrompt", 0);
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Please don't update the question with your answer. You should instead add your own answer below, explain how it works and how it fixes your issue. You should also accept it as __the__ answer when you're able.

Answer (score 0):

When the Model Error added, you can use this script to call alert:

In Controller, the modelError has been added by:

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
```

Then View to detect and show alert:

```
<script>
    @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        <text>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('@ViewData.ModelState[""].Errors.First().ErrorMessage');
        });
        </text>
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This does not match my criterias. I solved my problem using localStorage based javaScript that ran on a dynamic variable. Anyway, thanks for your help.